# Google maps geolocation.geolocate gives map, but not directions

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

So I've made this piece of code which turns an ordinary address into a geolocation and gives back a map and directions from your gps location (phonegap position, html5 location or whatever latlng). This function gets called on success of the phonegap or html5 location.

This code works fine in a browser but fails with a:
Error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object in file://bla bla at line 761

Line 761 = geocoder.geocode ( { 'address': address }, function(results, status)  {

So i've checked all my variables and they are not empty just like in the online version and the return div exists. So I'm guessing there is something wrong in the geolocator link to Google.

The funny thing though, it shows the map but not the directions. And it marks the location where you need to go, but not where you are. Its as if just directions just doesnt load or something.

```
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function bring_me_back(call_back_map,call_back_directions,address,position) {
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude); // your location
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: true
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(call_back_map),myOptions);
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById(call_back_directions));
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    title:"My location"
});
// find the address
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder (map);
geocoder.geocode ( { 'address': address }, function(results, status)  {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)  {
        var end = results [0].geometry.location;
        map.setCenter(results [0].geometry.location);
        marker.setPosition(results [0].geometry.location);
        var start = latlng; // your gps location 
        var request = {
            origin:start,
            destination:end,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            } else  alert("Directions was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        });
    }
    else {
        $('#'+call_back).html("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
});
}
```

The way I call google (it has plenty of time to load and "initialize" gets called way before I use this code).

```
function loadGoogleScript() {
if(!(navigator.network.connection.type == Connection.NONE)) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.6&sensor=false&callback=initialize';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

}

The feedback from the API is way to limited, so I can't make anything more of it.

Comment: is your geocoder object null?

Comment: Geocoder returns {}, seems right. and geocoder.geocode returns

    function (a, b) {S(Ke,function(c){c.geocode(a,b)});}

Answer (score 0):

After a hell of a search, I found out that one variable:

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
```

Was called before google script loaded. Changed it to

```
var directionsService;
```

And called:

```
directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
```

From inside the the function.

Thanks for help.